# Does lua_sethook trigger even in registered C functions?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, lua

Let's say I created a `boost::thread` that eventually calls `lua_pcall` which is blocking the thread until the end of the return of the script. I would like to use `lua_sethook` to monitor an escape condition and probably set a `boost::this_thread::interrupt_point()`, but does it also trigger during a call to a registered C function that the lua script calls?

The documentation specifies that the hook could be called after/before each instruction (or after each *n* instructions), but I think the C function call is compiled down to a `CALL` bytecode instruction. Therefore the hook would only be called when I return from the C function.

Is there anyway to have a *cooperative* thread termination in this case? I would like to avoid `TerminateThread` from the windows API. Everyone's saying to not use it.

**EDIT:** After testing it locally, I can answer my first question

> Does lua_sethook trigger even in registered C functions?

As I thought, no. Now, how can someone use cooperative thread termination in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question in the title: **No**, the lua_sethook doesn't trigger in registered C functions that can be called from the Lua side.

Also, to save some time for any people that might have the same idea that I did, I investigated a bit more about what kind of mechanism could be used to essentially stop the execution of a running C/C++ thread, save the context (memory, variables, etc.) go execute some custom code/thread termination condition monitoring piece of code (executed within the same thread) and then go back to the saved context or return to the lua script with a `lua_error` call to unwind the call stack and release resources properly. I tested all of these tools/mechanism and none could solve the issue to have a cooperative thread termination mechanism

- `TerminateThread` from the main thread to kill the lua/worker thread. Avoid at all cost, since it leaves the process' memory in an undefined state, doesn't release any resource, sometimes generate memory access violation
- `LibEvent` which can execute signal handlers within the same thread. For some reason when I tried it with example code it simply wasn't being called and didn't stop the thread execution
- `boost::asio`'s deadline timers which are async timers that can execute some custom routine in between the triggers. The worker's routine must be placed in the timers handlers code and won't stop a `while(true)` to execute for instance in the timer's routine.
- Windows' API `SetTimer` function  will create another thread to handle the signals, which just moves the problem (cannot exit the lua thread from the newly created thread)
- Interrupt signal handlers (in the particular case of Windows the `SIGTERM` signal is unhandled so I thought maybe I could use some custom routine with it): They can't be used because a `lua_error` call essentially comes down a `longjmp` which is not recommended by the MSDN documentation on interrupt signal handlers:

  > Do not use longjmp unless the interrupt is caused by a floating-point exception (that is, sig is SIGFPE). In this case, first reinitialize the floating-point package by using a call to _fpreset.

So once you're in a registered C++ function called from the Lua side you can't really get out of it forcefully without consequences.

**EDIT:**

**It was possible for me to get out of the thread forcefully**. In my case, I used `boost::thread` and called the `interrupt` function from the main thread. By putting a try/catch block around the `lua_pcall` instruction with a `boost::thread_interrupted` exception handler, I was able to safely call `lua_error` from C++, unwind the callstack properly and end the lua thread in a semi-cooperative way.